# Non-computable infinite subsets

Tags: computability

> Is there a computably enumerable set $A$ such that every infinite subset of $A$
>   is noncomputable?

I think that it's a set $K = \{n\ \ |\ \ U(n,n) \text{ is defined}\}$ (which is noncomputable, $U(n,x)$ is universal computable function).
But I can't understand, how to prove, that an *arbitrary* infinite subset of $K$ is noncomputable. What to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "insoluble"?  Also, are you familiar with the theorem that every infinite r.e. set has an infinite computable subset?

Comment: Uh oh, I fixed it. No, i don't.

Comment: That theorem will solve the question at hand, so try proving it first. Also, you almost certainly want to ask about *infinite* c.e. sets, to avoid trivialities, e.g. the c.e. set $\{0\}$ has no computable infinite subsets.

Comment: The usual argument is this: Assume $A$ is infinite and c.e. Start enumerating it, but don't print all the outputs. Say the first output is $n_0$. Print it, but then don't print any other output unless it is larger than $n_0$. The first such output you see, print it and call it $n_1$. Then don't print any other outputs until you see one that is larger than $n_1$, etc. Do you see how to formalize this algorithm, and why $\{n_0,n_1,\dots\}$ is computable?

Comment: Oh, i see now. Let $A$ be c. e. We run the enumerator $A$, delete duplicated elements and make a function $a(n)=\text{the number at n-th printed position}$. Then, we build these $\{n_0, n_1, ...\}$ (as you said) using $a(n)$ in increasing order. Then, it's really easy to say why this set is computable (if number n is founded in sequence, n is in set, else isn't in set). Thanks!